# Concurrently update list

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a list of accounts that will be updated  - not too frequent ~1-2 times a day.
There would be a 'contains' lookup on this data at much regular interval.
An ideal data structure would have been ConcurrentLinkedList  ,which unfortunately isnt around.
Is CopyOnWriteArrayList the sole preferred option?

Comment: Hi Why You are not thinking some kind of Tree or hash map data structure where look up will first

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` sounds perfect for your use case. What do you have against it?

Comment: You may be looking for  Set<Type> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Type, Boolean>());

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading mostly , why you need concurrent data structure. Instead you can use HashSet or HashMap. It will make read faster. It is updated so less frequently then u can synchronise the writing part explicitly.

Comment: This seems to be wrong ,because while one thread writing other  thread should not read stale data.

Comment: But it is updated so infrequent , you can take care of that explicitly using locks. right ?. Also Your reading performance should be faster in your case, List has o(n) complexity for contains.

Comment: then you have to implement read /write lock separately not explicit lock ,where multiple thread can read.May be set can be use  Set<Type> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Type, Boolean>());